# Is this a capacitor in series with the power source?

Tags: identification, components

I'm a complete newcomer here. I was looking at this small circuit and it looks like there is a capacitor connected in series with the power source. Is it possible that this is the case, or do capacitors always have to be connected in parallel with the power source?

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: What is the power source? If it's DC, a capacitor will block it completely - so it's probably not going to be a capacitor.

Comment: Polyfuse or varistor more than likely. A better picture would help.

Comment: I've added a better picture. I've taken this component from a KNEX DC motor that runs off 2XAA batteries

Comment: Agree above - I am "100% certain" that is not a capacitor, it's a polyfuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is a polyfuse/resettable fuse. It would make sense to be in series as it would break the circuit if it draws too much current. Polyfuses are often that yellow colour, but I'm unable to read the text on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very helpful. The text on it is C075 P8

Comment: @l33z3r I had a quick google, and I couldn't find any data sheet, but I did find what looks to be from the same manufacturer: [Telecom Thermistor PPTC Resettable Fuse](http://aolittel.sell.everychina.com/p-108536349-0zrc0015ff1e-telecom-thermistor-pptc-resettable-fuse-trg015-with-rated-voltage.html) I hope this helps

Comment: Cheers for your help. I am trying to understand some simple circuits and just couldn't figure out why this capacitor was connected in series. Obviously I need to research a new component. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!